# Can we `reinterpret_cast` a `Eigen::Vector<T, D + 1>& x` to `Eigen::Vector<T, D>&` to extract the first `D` components from `x`?

Tags: c++, c++20, eigen, reinterpret-cast

I need to compute the function value and gradient of a `D`-dimensional function and add those values together. I thought it would be computational beneficial to simply store the gradient part in the first `D`-components and the value of the function in the last component of a `D+1`-dimensional vector.

However, how can I extract the first `D`-components (i.e. the gradient part) from that `D+1`-dimensional vector? I know that there is the option of slicing, but I don't want to add any senseless overhead here. So, I've tried to simply do a `reinterpret_cast<Eigen::Vector<T, D>&>` on my `Eigen::Vector<T, D + 1>` and it worked; but is that really guaranteed to work (and safe)?

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, sorry. Fixed that.

Comment: Why not just `x.head<D>()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want the slicing operations, you want the [block operations](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialBlockOperations.html). Most (all?) of them come with template versions. To get the first `D` elements of a vector if `D` is a runtime variable, call `vector.head(D)`. If it is a compile-time constant, use `vector.head<D>()`.

The returned [block](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Block.html) expression object is similar to an Eigen [Map](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMapClass.html) in that it is effectively a zero-overhead reference and does exactly what you want.

```cpp
// act like reference
auto first_d = vector.head<D>();
// copy into new vector
auto copy = first_d.eval();
// or
Eigen::Vector<double, D> copy2 = first_d;
```

The usual warnings about [using `auto` in Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html) apply, but this use is okay. If you want to be safe, spell the type out or don't keep it around as a variable, only use it as part of expressions.

If you compile without [`-DNDEBUG`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicAssertions.html) there will be a range-check unless the compiler can optimize it away (likely the case for template parameter used on fixed-size vector).

And just to return to the **original question**: No, it would not be safe. Even if you trust that Eigen never changes the internal layout of fixed size types (reasonable assumption), smaller vectors may have bigger alignment. `alignof(Vector3d) < alignof(Vector2d)`. This will result in Eigen creating machine instructions that assume that higher alignment (such as `movapd` vs. `movupd` on x86), which will fail at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

It causes undefined behavior.

You may use members of a class through a glvalue only if that glvalue has a type that is *similar* to the type of the object. *Similar* means that the types are the same up to `const` qualifications.

When you use `reinterpret_cast` like this, you change the type of the lvalue, but you still let it refer to the same object with the original type. (There are certain exceptions to this if there is an object of the target type at the same address which is *pointer-interconvertible* with the original object, but I doubt that it is guaranteed that `Eigen::Vector` is implemented in such a way that `Eigen::Vector<T, D+1>` is standard-layout containing a `Eigen::Vector<T, D>` subobject at its beginning, which would be a prerequisite for the exception to apply.)

---

And even if you don't care about UB like that, at the very least you are making assumptions about the memory layout of the two classes. But nobody guarantees you that layout. (Still, even if it was guaranteed, it would still have UB regardless.)

Comment: So, I need to use `x(Eigen::seq(0, D - 1))` to extract the first `D` components of `x`? Is that performant?

Comment: @0xbadf00d I don't know enough about Eigen to answer that. What I wrote above applies on the language level to basically all class types (with exceptions that are not going to apply here).

Comment: Oh, but isn't it maybe then safe to reinterpret-cast? For example, if `template<std::size_t D> using point = std::array<int, D>`, then it would be safe to do `reinterpret_cast<point<D>&>(x)` on `point<D + 1> x`, woudn't it?

Comment: @0xbadf00d It would still have undefined behavior per the standard. If you trust that your compiler doesn't do anything unexpected with it, it may be fine, but I wouldn't call that "_really guaranteed to work (and safe)_" as you are asking in your question.